# OauthSampler from JMeter 3.0 to JMeter 3.3

Tags: plugins, jmeter, beanshell

I have a test plan that works great in JMeter 3.0 (it was conceived with this version).

I tried to upgrade JMeter to 3.3 and now I have few new errors.

```
2018-02-19 16:40:51,544 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default base='D:\Automation\bin'
2018-02-19 16:40:51,544 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='D:\Automation\bin'
2018-02-19 16:40:51,711 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2018-02-19 16:40:51,714 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2018-02-19 16:40:51,717 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 3.2
2018-02-19 16:40:51,721 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: D:\Automation\bin\ENDPOINT.jmx
2018-02-19 16:40:51,969 INFO o.a.j.p.h.c.CacheManager: Will only cache the following methods: [GET]
2018-02-19 16:40:52,048 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2018-02-19 16:40:52,048 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2018-02-19 16:40:52,048 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2018-02-19 16:40:52,048 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2018-02-19 16:40:52,048 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2018-02-19 16:40:52,048 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2018-02-19 16:40:52,321 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='D:\Automation\bin'
2018-02-19 16:40:52,670 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2018-02-19 16:40:52,671 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2018-02-19 16:40:52,671 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2018-02-19 16:40:52,671 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2018-02-19 16:40:53,049 WARN o.j.r.Plugin: Unable to load class: com.atlantbh.jmeter.plugins.oauth.OAuthSampler
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampler2
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.Plugin.getJARPath(Plugin.java:193) [jmeter-plugins-manager-0.19.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.Plugin.detectInstalledPlugin(Plugin.java:107) [jmeter-plugins-manager-0.19.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.Plugin.detectInstalled(Plugin.java:96) [jmeter-plugins-manager-0.19.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.load(PluginManager.java:84) [jmeter-plugins-manager-0.19.jar:?]
    at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerMenuItem$1.run(PluginManagerMenuItem.java:41) [jmeter-plugins-manager-0.19.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    ... 16 more
```

How can I overcome this error? I know that [OAuth Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/OAuthSampler/) is deprecated. Is there a way to fix this? Also I have some error when I try to read from a file (might not be related).

```
2018-02-19 16:41:07,229 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``{import org.ini4j.*; Wini ini = new Wini(new File(vars.get("SettingsFile"))); St . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: Wini not found in namespace
2018-02-19 16:41:07,229 WARN o.a.j.f.BeanShell: Error running BSH script
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``{import org.ini4j.*; Wini ini = new Wini(new File(vars.get("SettingsFile"))); St . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: Wini not found in namespace
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter.bshInvoke(BeanShellInterpreter.java:183) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter.eval(BeanShellInterpreter.java:189) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.BeanShell.execute(BeanShell.java:100) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:137) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:112) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:92) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsString(AbstractTestElement.java:281) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.Argument.getValue(Argument.java:146) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments.getArgumentsAsMap(Arguments.java:94) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.PreCompiler.createArgumentsMap(PreCompiler.java:114) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.PreCompiler.addNode(PreCompiler.java:101) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:996) [jorphan.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:978) [jorphan.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:369) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter.bshInvoke(BeanShellInterpreter.java:166) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Copy from your old directory of JMETER_HOME\lib\ext all the missing jars which not exists (also not with upgraded jar version) to your new lib\ext directory

Comment: But, if OAuth Sampler doesn't have support for JMeter 3.2+, is it safe to do?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into commit [`2651c6ffc534e0137849377fce4b1b0e1aafca47`](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1783280) the file `src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampler2.java` has been removed as a part of [issue 60727](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60727) during [JMeter 3.2 release](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html)

So maximum JMeter version you can use with OAuth Sampler is **JMeter 3.1**.

You can reach out to JMeter Plugins developers and/or maintainers via [JMeter Plugins Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins) and clarify the status and the plans or use one of alternative approaches described in [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter), they should be JMeter-version-agnostic.

You can download JMeter 3.1 from [Apache JMeter Archives](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/) page